# Is there a CheckBoxListCell equivalent for JFoenix so that we can use JFXCheckBox instead of the traditional one?

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

So I am currently using my JFXListView and trying to set several checkboxes inside of it using CheckBoxListCell. Originally I used this:

```
listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<classForMenuOptions, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(UserMenuOptions item) {
                return item.selectedProperty();
            }
}));
```

Is there a way so that I can use JFXCheckBox instead of the traditional CheckBox?

Comment: JFoenix has horrendous documentation, but have you tried looking into how the `JFXCheckBox` is implemented? There may be some way to extend its usefulness.

Comment: As @Zephyr  points out, the documentation of _JFoenix_ is just terrible. Looking at the Javadoc (which I couldn't find online, had to download from Maven) there doesn't appear to be any built-in cell for this. You'll have to do as [Sedrick does in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071664/6395627) and create your own cell in a cell factory. You can get more inspiration (if needed) by looking at how [`CheckBoxListCell` is implemented in JavaFX](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxListCell.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to implement your own `cellFactory`.

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewExperiments extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListView Experiment 1");

        JFXListView<String> listView = new JFXListView<>();
        listView.setPrefWidth(200);
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>()
        {
            JFXCheckBox checkBox = new JFXCheckBox();

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    //setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
                else {
                    checkBox.setText(item);
                    setGraphic(checkBox);
                }
            }
        });
        listView.getItems().add("Item 1");
        listView.getItems().add("Item 2");
        listView.getItems().add("Item 3");

        HBox hbox = new HBox(listView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 300, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]